# How to select all <li> in an <ul> with a classname "nav"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

Having a real hard time with this since I'm new to jQuery, but I'm not sure whether the tutorial I'm working on is broken or if it's me but I'm using the following code to select all li in an ul with a class of nav.

```
$(".nav ul li");
```

Is this correct? Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Remember that jQuery selectors are just like css selectors.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Constructively,

1. All `ul` elements:

   ```
   $("ul")
   ```
2. All `ul` elements with a classname `nav`:

   ```
   $("ul.nav")
   ```
3. All `li` elements under all `ul` elements with a classname `nav`:

   ```
   $("ul.nav li")
   ```

Comment: awesome! Thanks! $("ul.nav li") worked just fine. Still trying to wrap my head around this and why that works. :)

Comment: @KenBarlo: You can learn how it works by learning css, more info here http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/

Answer (score 13):

Here's a tip that will help people learn selectors:

Use the Chrome browser
Open up any page
Right click on the page and select "Inspect element"
In the element inspector select the Console tab

You can type commands right into this console.  Try a few selectors only and see what you get. If you type $('p') and hit enter it will list out all the p elements. If you enter $('ul.nav li) it will show you if that selector works (returns anything).  If the command does not result in a valid selector it will return [].

Answer (score 2):

Append it after the [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector):

```
$("ul.nav li");
```

This selects all `<li>` elements in a `<ul class="nav">` element

See the docs: http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Answer (score 2):

> select all li in an ul with a class of nav

like so, selects all li's in an ul with the `.nav` class:

```
$('ul.nav li')
```

Answer (score 2):

All li in an ul with a class of nav:

```
$("ul.nav li");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul.nav li')
```

As suggested selects ALL the `<li />` in `<ul class="nav" />`.
If you only want the immediate children use:

```
$('ul.nav > li')
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator